# Facebook Post Object in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi i am writing Facebook Application, and here i am using Post Object to post message of Friends Wall and i am able to post as well,

But my problem is I am getting Image link as well while click on Text I have given (Wishing....) as you can see in below screen shot

So here i need a small help, how can i remove this link...

I have given this text message in Strings.xml:

```
   <string name="app_action">Wishing you a birthday as special as you are! Hope this is a new beginning to lots of great things and happy moments in your life. Wish you a fabulous birthday!</string>
```

[image]

ImageLink:

```
  public static final String HACK_ICON_URL = "http://i1.pickupflowers.com/images/puf/images/product/large/carnations-lilies-and-roses.jpg";
```

My Code:

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "fql.query");
    params.putString("query", query);
    FacebookUtility.asyncRunner.request(null, params, new FacebookRequestListener(FacebookRequestListener.FRIENDS, facebookRequest));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not setting the post parameters up properly. See the code i have used for this:

```
 Bundle postParams = new Bundle();

        postParams.putString("name", getString(R.string.fbPostName));
        postParams.putString("caption", getString(R.string.fbPostCaption));
        postParams.putString("description", getString(R.string.fbPostDescription).replace("(Venue)",venueName ));
        postParams.putString("link", getString(R.string.fbPostLink));
        postParams.putString("picture", getString(R.string.fbPostPicture));
```

The last two lines of codes are setting the link for both, the picture and the link.